# Is the Angular Language Service extension in VSCode supposed to highlight the syntax of bound attributes?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I have the `angular.ng-template` extension (v14.2.0) installed in VSCode (v1.71.2) but it doesn't do any syntax highlighting on bound attribute values. For example, on the following line

```html
        <form action="/api/user" method="post" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
```

All the characters in the strings `"form"` and `"submit()"` appear in the default color for HTML attribute values. However, expressions enclosed in handlebars (`{{}}`) inside elements *are* highlighted in different colors.

I can't figure out if this is the way it's supposed to behave now. On one hand, I found some open issues (for example, [this one](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/1725)) related to this in the extension's GitHub repo, and I also seem to remember it worked properly two years ago. On the other hand, in the [animation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/main/demo.gif) that appears in the extension's [README.md](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service#readme), it doesn't seem to highlight the microsyntax in the attribute `(click)="onClick()"`.

So I don't know whether I should open a new bug report about this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the extension has some highlight bug. I talked with the developer about it and the main workaround I found was to not use it while it's bugged and use the extension [vscode-angular-syntax](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dunstontc.vscode-angular-syntax).

Comment: `vscode-angular-syntax` doesn't seem to work, either... Even after disabling `angular.ng-template`.

Comment: Can try disabling all extension except `vscode-angular-syntax`?

Comment: Today I got to use this extension on a different computer and the syntax highlighting worked without any problems. Must be something in my settings or some other extension I have installed.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggest you to disable other extension, and then trying to isolate the one causing the error

Comment: I disabled a couple dozen extensions and uninstalled a few others and indeed it fixed the problem. Thanks!